# Expo inserting gif from keyboard like react-native-image-keyboard

Tags: expo

Trying to insert GIFs from the users keyboard to a chat interface but can't find anywhere in the docs or any refs online on how to get it working. react-native-image-keyboard is the go to for rn-cli but it has native code which makes it incompatible with expo. Is there something simple I'm missing or is this just not supported?

Tried using react-native-image-keyboard in expo and it did nothing as I kind of expected. Expo docs give no clue.